# How do I install and build Generic Mapping Tools version 6.0.0 or above?

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, cmake

I tried to install generic mapping tools v6.0.0 according to [instructions](https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/BUILDING.md#ubuntudebian). I failed to install it. I thought I carried out installing and building GMT v6.0.0.

`gmt not found, but can be installed with sudo apt install gmt`. It is for GMT v5.4.5

Should I install GMT v6.0.0 via GMT5 as follows for the first step?

For example,

`sudo apt-get install gmt gmt-dcw gmt-gshhg`

**EDIT**: My problem stemmed from setting path.

Comment: use the apt search to see the version and if that isn't the latest then you can use that method to install it. What were the errors when you used the instructions?

Comment: Did you use the command `cmake --build .` to install it?

Comment: I didn't get any of errors when I installed it. I merely got error `gmt not found, but can be installed with sudo apt , install gmt` when I finished installation.

Comment: I though I respectively configured `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..` and so on. I tired this way before but I am not sure.

Comment: Let me try and install it from my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used these steps to install it:

1. Install the required tools

   ```
   sudo apt install cdftools cmake
   sudo apt install build-essential libcurl4-gnutls-dev libnetcdf-dev
   ```
2. Download the source with:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/releases/download/6.0.0/gmt-6.0.0-src.tar.xz
   ```
3. Untar the source file:

   ```
   tar -xvf gmt-6.0.0-src.tar.xz
   ```
4. Install the GSHHG and DCW-GMT:

   ```
   sudo apt install gmt-gshhg-full
   sudo apt install gmt-dcw
   ```

   - Locate these files using the command:

     ```
     dpkg -L gmt-gshhg-full
     dpkg -L gmt-dcw
     ```
5. Configuring:

   GMT can be built on any platform supported by CMake. CMake is a cross-platform, open-source system for managing the build process. The building process is controlled by two configuration files in the cmake directory:

   ConfigDefault.cmake is version controlled and used to add new default variables and set defaults for everyone. You should NOT edit this file.
   ConfigUser.cmake is not version controlled and used to override defaults on a per-user basis. There is a template file, ConfigUserTemplate.cmake, that you should copy to ConfigUser.cmake and make your changes therein.
   In the source tree, copy the template configuration file cmake/ConfigUserTemplate.cmake to cmake/ConfigUser.cmake, and edit the file according to your demands. This is an example:

   ```
   set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr/local)
   set (GSHHG_ROOT /usr/share/gmt-gshhg)
   set (DCW_ROOT /usr/share/gmt-dcw)
   set (COPY_GSHHG true)
   set (COPY_DCW true)
   ```
6. Change into the untared folder and run the following commands:

   ```
   cd gmt-6.0.0
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake ..
   cmake --build .
   cmake --build . --target install
   ```
7. Find the location of the installed tool if you didn't set it yourself:

   ```
   which gmt
   ```
8. You also need to download support data:

   ```
   [GSHHG][1]: A Global Self-consistent, Hierarchical, High-resolution 
   Geography Database (>=2.2.0)
   [DCW-GMT][1]: The Digital Chart of the World (optional, >=1.0.5)
   ```
9. Optional libraries as needed:

   - Install optional dependencies

     ```
      sudo apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev libfftw3-dev libpcre3-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev libglib2.0-dev ghostscript
     ```
   - to enable movie-making

     ```
      sudo apt install graphicsmagick ffmpeg
     ```
   - to enable document viewing via gmt docs

     ```
      sudo apt install xdg-utils
     ```
   - to enable testing

     ```
      sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
     ```
   - to build the documentation

     ```
      sudo apt install python-sphin
     ```

Update:

Setting path

```
Make sure you set the PATH to include the directory containing the GMT executables if this is not a standard directory like /usr/local/bin.

For Linux/macOS users, open your SHELL configuration file (usually ~/.bashrc) and add the line below to it.

export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/gmt/bin
Then, you should now be able to run GMT programs.
```

Note: More information for fine tuning your install can be found [here](https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt/blob/master/BUILDING.md#ubuntudebian)

Comment: Should I configure `cp ./cmake/ConfigUserTemplate.cmake ./cmake/ConfigUser.cmake` before 4th item or step?

Comment: I didn't and is only required if you want to make user specific changes to your build process!

Comment: So it is not necessary to get GMT source `git clone https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt`. Your processing second and third items instead of getting this? In addition, how do you set path if you don't configure? Guide me, please.

Comment: You asked for version 6 but you can use that if you want and see the update for how to set the path

Comment: When I tried your way, I got error. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @chess_freak what was the error please post it?

Comment: As far as I remember, it was related to tar, so 3rd list. Thank you again. I installed it.

Comment: Thank for the feedback I've seen the error I should have use `tar -xvf` not `tar -cvf` as it was, I have updated the answer. Please kindly click the accept button at the side of the question if it helped you.

Comment: Have you ever tried any code when you install it?

Comment: No just installed on a vm Ubuntu version 19.10!

Comment: I think your path is incorrect if you don't set path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102531/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-chess-freak).

Answer (score 0):

> **Note**: The Ubuntu package under 16.04 LTS for mysterious reasons does
>   not include the supplements. If you need them you will need to build
>   from source or upgrade to 18.04 LTS.

1. Learn your user ID using `whoami`. Let's say your user ID is *user*.
2. For example, I'd like to install this software in *Documents*.

```
install_dir='/home/user/Documents/gmt-6.0.0-src'
mkdir "$install_dir"
cd "$install_dir"
```

3. Install dependencies for Ubuntu/Debian.

```
sudo apt-get install subversion build-essential cmake libgdal-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libnetcdf-dev libfftw3-dev libpcre3-dev liblapack-dev libblas-dev gdal-bin libglib2.0-dev ghostscript graphicsmagick ffmpeg cdftools
```

4. Getting GMT source code

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/GenericMappingTools/gmt.git GMT
cd  GMT
```

5. Download supported data

```
wget ftp://ftp.soest.hawaii.edu/gshhg/gshhg-gmt-2.3.7.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.soest.hawaii.edu/dcw/dcw-gmt-1.1.4.tar.gz
tar xvf gshhg-gmt-2.3.7.tar.gz
tar xvf dcw-gmt-1.1.4.tar.gz
```

6. Configuring

```
cp ./cmake/ConfigUserTemplate.cmake ./cmake/ConfigUser.cmake
```

- Edit ConfigUser.cmake. Use codes respectively as follows...

```
sed -i 's|#set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "prefix_path")|set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX '"$install_dir"')|g' "$install_dir"/GMT/cmake/ConfigUser.cmake
sed -i 's|#set (GSHHG_ROOT "gshhg_path")|set (GSHHG_ROOT '"$install_dir\/GMT\/$gshhg"')|g' "$install_dir"/GMT/cmake/ConfigUser.cmake
sed -i 's|#set (DCW_ROOT "dcw-gmt_path")|set (DCW_ROOT '"$install_dir\/GMT\/$dcw"')|g' "$install_dir"/GMT/cmake/ConfigUser.cmake
sed -i 's|#set (COPY_GSHHG TRUE)|set (COPY_GSHHG TRUE)|g' "$install_dir"/GMT/cmake/ConfigUser.cmake
sed -i 's|#set (COPY_DCW TRUE)|set (COPY_DCW TRUE)|g' "$install_dir"/GMT/cmake/ConfigUser.cmake
```

7. Building and installing

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

8. Setting path

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:$install_dir/bin" >> ~/.profile
. ~/.profile
```

9. Test it.

```
cd "$install_dir"
gmt begin GMT_tut_3
gmt coast -R-90/-70/0/20 -JM6i -B -Gchocolate
gmt end show
```

10. [Documentation](https://docs.generic-mapping-tools.org/latest/tutorial.html)

**NOTE:** Tested for Ubuntu 19.10